# Simple Userscript is slow and sometimes doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey, userscripts

just as a side note I am new to JS and this is my first script.

I am writing a small script that should allow me to open the biggest available image in a flickr page in an unfocused newtab using a keyboard shortcut.

I am currently facing two problems:

1. The script is slow at loading, meaning that if I change the image in the slideshow using the arrow keys, I will need to wait 1 or 2 seconds before pressing the keyboard shortcut to open the image in the newtab. If I don't wait, it will open one of the previous images from the slideshow in the newtab depending on how fast I was skipping through them. (It should always open the image I am currently viewing in a newtab)
2. I use log(mainurl) to print the current contents of "mainurl" which is the link to the biggest available size of the current opened image. but for some reason it is always giving me the url of one of the previous images depending on how fast I am skipping through the slideshow (even though the correct image is opened in the newtab).

Here is a URL to a flickr account if you want to check the script. (it must be run in the photostream [slideshow mode]) [URL to flickr photostream](https://www.flickr.com/photos/tohru_nishimura/49017276147/in/photostream/)

This is the code I wrote

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Flickr Max NewTab
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      1.0
// @description  Open Max sized flickr image in a new tab using key shorcut
// @author       Newbie
// @include     /flickr\.com/
// @grant       GM_openInTab
// @require     https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

var page ='';
var sizes = [];
var links = [];
var length = 0;
var mainurl = '';

function geturl() { // function used to get the link of biggest image
    var action = function (sourceCode) {
        sizes = sourceCode.match(/modelExport: {.+?"sizes":{.+?}}/i); // extract the part of html that containes modelExport:
        links = sizes[0].match(/"displayUrl":"[^"]+"/ig); // extract the urls dictionary from the dictionary modelExport:
        length = links.length; //get the length of the dictionary "links"
        // extract the last(biggest) url from the links dictionary and put them in an array "links"
        mainurl = links[links.length-1].replace(/"displayUrl":"([^"]+)"/i, "$1").replace(/\\/g, "").replace(/(_[a-z])\.([a-z]{3,4})/i, '$1' + "." + '$2');
    }
    $.get(document.URL, action);
}

function log(x) {
    console.log(x);
}
// function used to get to run the url grabber everytime you change the image in slideshow using arrowkeys
function navigation (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 39) {
        geturl();
        log(mainurl);// log to check the current contents of mainurl
    }
}
// function used to open image in a newtab when "alt + Q" are pressed
function newtab (e) {
    if (e.altKey && e.keyCode == 81) {
        GM_openInTab(mainurl);
    }
}

geturl(); //run the function

document.addEventListener('keyup', navigation);
document.addEventListener('keydown', newtab);
```

Thanks a lot for any help !

Comment: I think this question might be better for CodeReview.SE - that site is dedicated to reviewing short code samples from beginners and your code is short enough to be 100% on topic.

Comment: thank you @TomášZato will go check it out

Comment: Note that your post is not off topic here at all, just a suggestion for future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to intercept the existing fast request made by the site to its server API (you can inspect it in devtools network panel) instead of making an additional slow request.

For that we will use `unsafeWindow` and hook `XMLHttpRequest` prototype. Also run the script at `document-start` so it attaches the interceptor before the page makes the request.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Flickr Max NewTab
// @match       https://www.flickr.com/*
// @grant       GM_openInTab
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

const xhrOpen = unsafeWindow.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
unsafeWindow.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (method, url) {
  if (/method=[^&]*?(getPhotos|getInfo)/.test(url)) {
    this.addEventListener('load', onXhrLoad, {once: true});
  }
  return xhrOpen.apply(this, arguments);
};

const imgUrls = {};

function onXhrLoad() {
  const json = JSON.parse(this.response);
  const photos = json.photos ? json.photos.photo : [json.photo];
  for (const {id, url_o} of photos) {
    imgUrls[id] = url_o;
  }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.altKey && e.code === 'KeyQ' && !e.shiftKey && !e.ctrlKey && !e.metaKey) {
    const id = location.pathname.split('/')[3];
    const url = imgUrls[id];
    if (url) GM_openInTab(url, true);
  }
});
```

Comment: Wanted to post an answer using the script text content but then realized the page updates via ajax and reached the same conclusion. Did you however find the max resolution in the JSON? I couldn't find it in any of the requests.

Comment: @wOxxOm the code works great on the url I gave you, even though I dont understand most of the code, will have to read it carefully.
But the code does not work on different pages because the biggest image doesnt always end with "_o" it might have different post fixes "_6k" , "_5k" , "_l" ..etc

Comment: @Vagabond The trick is that whenever Flickr app tries to fetch some photo info, wOxxOm's script also gets that info without aditional downloading of data. You can inspect the data Fickr downloads in your dev tools under "Network" panel (it's those that have JSON format).

Comment: @TomášZato , I dont see any JSON in the network, I see XHR though which is the one that is always being sent when i change the image

Comment: You need to reload the page with devtools open and there'll be a batch request for 20 images at once with the words "per_page" in the URL.

Comment: Here's a screenshot where to look for, but it may look differently in other browsers: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XimzQ.png Next to "Origin" column, there's a "Type" column, which shows what type of data the server announced it is sending.

Comment: ok so the code that @wOxxOm provided works great, but it only works for 20 images so if I continue scrolling past 20 images, i can't download anymore

Comment: See the updated code. There was a different `flickr.photos.getInfo` request for subsequent images.

Comment: @wOxxOm yeah now it works, Guess what is left is for me to figure out how to make the code take the next biggest available size after "_o" if it is not available.
Thanks a bunch m8, I will try to study the code and ask if there is anything I can't understand from it. soz I can't +1 the answer cause I dont have enough rep :D

Comment: Inspect the response in devtools and you'll see the "photo" object has many `url_???` fields with the corresponding widths/heights fields.

Comment: @wOxxOm , yeah I know, it goes in this order [ o, 6k, 5k, 4k, 3k, k, l, h ....etc]
but I will have to understand the code to make it choose the next biggest image if "_o" is not available :)